# RNotebook not picking up default figure sizes

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, rnotebook

Say, I have the following **RNotebook** chunk that plots a figure:

````
```{r}
plot(cars)
```
````

Now, I want to plot it as a 10x10 figure. I could use this:

````
```{r fig.height = 10, fig.width = 10}
plot(cars)
```
````

and that works fine. But say I want to redefine global figure sizes and default to those. I tried using this:

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.height = 10, fig.width = 10)
plot(cars)
knitr::opts_chunk$get()$fig.width
knitr::opts_chunk$get()$fig.height
```
````

but this doesn't resize the figure correctly and yet the default figure sizes have been changed when I check them. Can someone explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried putting `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.height = 10, fig.width = 10)` in your setup chunk?

Comment: I think that's fine if I don't want to change those parameters part way through my notebook, which is what I'm trying to do. It looks like this is something that RNotebook can't really handle at present.

Comment: What about putting the options "fig.width=10, fig.height=10" in the chunk header?

Answer (score 0):

A little playing around and, with an `html_document` output type, it works if you put the `opts_chunk` call in the chunk ahead of where you want it to be used.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document
---

```{r, setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 5)
```

```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 8)
```

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 12)
```

```{r}
plot(cars)
```
````